# How can I add a scroll bar to a fixed sidebar that only appears on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a site where I made the sidebar to be fixed on the left and extended to the full height of the page using this CSS:

```
sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And that works fine to keep the sidebar in place, but the problem is when the page is re-sized to a smaller height, you can only see the stuff at the top of the sidebar and there's no way to see the stuff at the bottom of the sidebar.

Now, I know I can add a scroll bar using `overflow-y: scroll;` but what I'm trying to do is have a scroll bar that only appears when the content on the sidebar exceeds the height of the window and only appears on hover. I also want the scroll bar to have some style to it, similar to the sidebar on [TheNextWeb](http://thenextweb.com/) or the Facebook chat sidebar.

I know I need some JavaScript to do this, but my skills in JavaScript are very limited so I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`overflow-y: auto` should work:

For styling you should probably search for a good scrollbar-replacement, as scrollbar-styling only works in webkit (http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/). It's not a trivial thing to do, but fortunately there are some plugins:

- http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4
- http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
- http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/

Just to mention a few.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to sheba, I made some modfications:

```
.sidebar:hover{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/GcLFn

Comment: You should also set this css attribute to happen on hover, by making siderbar { ... } and sidebar:hover { overflow-y: auto; }

Comment: Thanks for the help, the overflow on hover works better, now I just need to work it out so it doesn't shift my content on hover.